# How to override wincmd.ini location?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, total-commander

How to override `wincmd.ini` location after [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) was installed? I can't seem to find a menu item for this setting. Where is this setting stored? Operating system is Windows XP or Windows 7 32bit.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Updated issue description.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, edit wincmd.ini, look for `UseIniInProgramDir=` and set it to 7.

> UseIniInProgramDir=Flags sum 
>   This variable will only be read if the wincmd.ini is located in the same dir as the program. 
>   It is the sum of the following values : 
>   0: Disabled 
>   1: Use wincmd.ini in the program-dir. if no other location is set via the registry or parameters 
>   2: Use wcx_ftp.ini in the program-dir. if no other location is set via the registry or parameters 
>   4: Override the registry settings (but not the command line parameters)

Then, edit the shortcut to Total Commander so that it looks like this:

```
TC_path\TOTALCMD.EXE /i=config_path/wincmd.ini
```

Where TC_path is the path to totalcmd.exe and config_path is the desired path to wincmd.ini

Comment: I'm using the v8.01, there is no setting like UseIniInProgramDir. Did it change?

Comment: Just try creating the entry, it should work.

Comment: wincmd.ini is not user-writable on my workplace computer, that is the very reason I want to override it with my own :( is it possible? or do I need to install a portable version?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to move the ini-file;
You can use the tool inireloc from the Total Commander addons page at:
http://www.ghisler.com
or check:
http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=135417

Answer (score 1):

I've needed this too, But for 2 files: wincmd.ini and wcx_ftp.ini.

```
totalcmd.exe /I=%pdrive%/totalcmd/MyCMDs.ini /F=%pdrive%/totalcmd/MyFTP.ini
```

I made a copy of the original files and renamed them for personal reference. You might have to change directories: Mine is `c:\totalcmd\`.

Answer (score 1):

While I use the command-line arguments in shortcuts (.lnk files) when running from my thumbdrive, on my machine I set the registry to the location I want. This allows me to change the name of the `wincmd.ini` file per machine, without worrying about which shortcut to run.

The registry location is here (displayed as a .REG file):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ghisler]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Ghisler\Total Commander]
"IniFileName"="%AppData%\\Ghisler\\wincmd-%COMPUTERNAME%.ini"
"FtpIniName"="%AppData%\\Ghisler\\wcx_ftp.ini"
"InstallDir"="%SystemDrive%\\totalcmd"
```

To apply the same location to the whole system (all users), use the following key instead. But, settings in each user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` key will still override `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Ghisler\Total Commander]
```

NOTE: You will probably have to replace the envars in my example with real locations before importing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a detailed explanation of where total commander looks for it's ini files. I personally use the registry method to relocate mine:

http://www.ghisler.ch/wiki/index.php/Finding_the_paths_of_Total_Commander_files

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please include the relevant information from the link in your answer? This will make sure your answer remains useful even if the linked page changes or disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the two files to your TC program folder and put this line in the [Configuration] section of your wincmd.ini file:

UseIniInProgramDir=7

---

BETTER:
Use IniReloc: 
http://ghisler.fileburst.com/addons/inireloc.zip